# Installed react dom rather than react-dom. What's the difference?

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-dom

kind of new at this and typed in "install react dom" instead of "install react-dom" in my command prompt. What exactly is the difference and what did I install?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it means you installed the [`react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react) package and [`dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom) package instead of the [`react-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom) package. That `dom` package is not related to React or React-DOM in any way. You probably want both React and React-DOM:

```
npm install react react-dom
```